# Long note in modelsummary

Tags: r, modelsummary

I was wondering, whether it is possible to align text on both sides in notes using `modelsummary`. It would be great if the note would look similar to notes in this paper https://www.econ.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:a68d7a76-93af-4ceb-86aa-344d6ee8d0c6/dodging%20the%20taxman%20AEJ%20Applied.pdf (in particular similar to that on page 151).

In markdown notes look fine. Once I export to .tex the text is somewhat misaligned.

Here is the code that I used.

```
library("modelsummary")

#small example:
x<-rnorm(5)
y<-rnorm(5)
modelsummary(list(lm(y~x),lm(y~x)),notes = "this is my very very very very very very long note this is my very very very very very very long note",output = "test.tex")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default output for the `modelsummary` function is a table drawn by the `kableExtra` package. It looks like `kableExtra` supports the LaTeX `threeparttable` package which, I believe, allows you to left-and-right justify footnotes. To learn how to customize `kableExtra` tables, I strongly recommend you read the excellent LaTeX-focused vignette which [can be found on the `kableEtra` website](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/).

If you don't like the default footnotes supplied by `modelsummary`, for example, you can create your own using the `footnote` function from `kableExtra`. To do this, you need to specify `"latex"` as your output format, then apply the `footnote` function, then finally save the table with `save_kable`.

This code should bring you very close to the desired result, but note that `kableExtra` allows lots of ways to customize almost everything about your table:

```r
library("modelsummary")
library("kableExtra")

x<-rnorm(5)
y<-rnorm(5)

m <- list(lm(y~x),lm(y~x))
n <- "this is my very very very very very very long note this is my very very very very very very long note"

modelsummary(m, output = "latex") %>%
    footnote(general = n, threeparttable = TRUE) %>%
    save_kable(file = "~/Downloads/test.tex")
```

[image]